# Tests in circleci wont pass after upgrading ruby and heroku to 20 from 18

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium-webdriver, heroku, capybara, circleci-2.0

I am currently working on an app that uses ruby on rails on the backend and react.js on the front end.

Since Heroku 18 is ending, I decided to start the upgrade to Heroku 20 which will be available till 2025. Since doing so, I have been banging my head against the wall for 2 days. I have updated my dependancies as I believe fit based on documentation, but now 3 of my tests keep failing (using selenium-webdriver, webdriver, and capybarra). The error thrown shows this:

```
Failures:

  1) Posts create post
     Failure/Error: fill_in :user_email, with: user.email
     
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find visible field :user_email that is not disabled
     # ./spec/support/auth_helper.rb:5:in `login_as'
     # ./spec/features/beneficiary/posts/post_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:46:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) donor dashboard should have nav elements
     Failure/Error: fill_in :user_email, with: user.email
     
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find visible field :user_email that is not disabled
     # ./spec/support/auth_helper.rb:5:in `login_as'
     # ./spec/features/donor/dashboard_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:46:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Posts create post
     Failure/Error: fill_in :user_email, with: user.email
     
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find visible field :user_email that is not disabled
     # ./spec/support/auth_helper.rb:5:in `login_as'
     # ./spec/features/donor/posts/post_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:46:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

In the file auth_helper, the format for the fill_in seems to be the issue, but looking at the documentation and confirming the id for user_email to be correct, I don't really understand what is happening at all. I feel like this might be a red herring as it really doesn't seem to be an issue on other tests that use the same method login_as. I tried upping the capybarra timeout time limit as well, and it still seems to fail to the page is certainly loading.

These tests are also passing locally, and only fail when i run them through circleci, which has me baffled and without much understanding of what to try next.

```
def login_as(user, password: "password")
  visit root_path

  find('a', text: 'Login').click
  fill_in :user_email, with: user.email
  fill_in :user_password, with: password
  find("input[value='Log in']").click
end
```

The referenced lines in rails_helper are databaseCleaner and example run lines below:

```
  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end
```

My config.yml is:

```
# CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
version: 2.1

orbs:
  browser-tools: circleci/browser-tools@1.4.0

jobs:

  build:
  
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
       - image: cimg/ruby:3.0.5-browsers # circleci/ruby:2.7.0-node-browsers 
         environment:
          PGHOST: 127.0.0.1
          PGUSER: $HEROKU_APP_NAME
          RAILS_ENV: test
          BUNDLER_VERSION: 2.0.2
      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
       - image: circleci/postgres:9.5-alpine
         environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: $HEROKU_APP_NAME
          POSTGRES_DB: $HEROKU_APP_NAME_test
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $HEROKU_APP_NAME
       - image: redis:4.0.10

    working_directory: ~/repo

    steps:
      - checkout
      - browser-tools/install-browser-tools

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
          # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
          - v1-dependencies-

      - run:
          name: Swap node versions
          command: |
            set +e
            wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.1/install.sh | bash
            export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
            [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
            [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
            nvm install v14
            nvm alias default 14.21.1

            echo 'export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"' >> $BASH_ENV
            echo '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"' >> $BASH_ENV

      - run:
          name: Configure Bundler
          command: |
            echo 'export BUNDLER_VERSION=$(cat Gemfile.lock | tail -1 | tr -d " ")' >> $BASH_ENV
            source $BASH_ENV
            gem install bundler

      - run:
          name: install dependencies
          command: |
            bundle config set --local path 'vendor/bundle'
            bundle install --jobs=4 --retry=3 
      # --path vendor/bundle


      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ./vendor/bundle
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}

      # Database setup
      - run: bundle exec rails db:create
      - run: bundle exec rails db:schema:load

      # frontend
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - sell-more-yarn-cache-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
            - sell-more-yarn-cache-{{ .Branch }}-
            - sell-more-yarn-cache-
     
      - run:
          name: Yarn Install
          command: |
            yarn --ignore-engines --cache-folder ~/.cache/yarn

      - save_cache:
          key: sell-more-yarn-cache-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
          paths:
            - ~/.cache/yarn
      
      - run:
          name: Webpacker Pre-Compile
          command: bundle exec rails webpacker:compile

      # run tests!
      - run:
          name: run tests
          command: |
            bundle exec rspec --profile 10 \
              --out test_results/rspec.xml \
              --format progress \
              $(circleci tests glob "spec/**/*_spec.rb" | circleci tests split --split-by=timings)

      # collect reports
      - store_test_results:
          path: /tmp/test-results
      - store_artifacts:
          path: /tmp/test-results
          destination: test-results

workflows:
  version: 2
  build-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
```

Versions:

```
    ruby '3.0.5'
    gem 'rails', '~> 6.1'

    group :test do
      gem 'capybara', '~> 3.38'
      gem 'database_cleaner'
      gem 'factory_bot_rails', '~> 6.2.0'
      gem 'rack_session_access'
      gem 'rails-controller-testing'
      gem 'rspec-rails'
      gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 4.0'
      gem 'shoulda-callback-matchers', '~> 1.1.1'
      gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 4.4'
      gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
      gem 'stripe-ruby-mock', github: 'rebelidealist/stripe-ruby-mock'
      gem 'timecop'
      gem 'webdrivers', '~> 5.2'
      gem 'webmock'
    end
```

Anyone have any ideas to help me get past this as I am falling behind on time and could really use a point in the right direction!

Thanks in advance!

I am expecting these tests to pass as they can locally and should be able to on circleci as they were right before the upgrade.

Comment: Start by outputting `page.html` to the logfile so you can see what the page actually has on it.  Also `fill_in` defines the first parameter as type string, not symbol - so you really should be doing `fill_in 'user_email', ...`, etc.  The fact that symbols have been working is just luck, and will most likely stop working in the next major capybara release

Comment: Do you use "print page.html" to do this? I haven't done it before? In which case, where would you put that? In the spec test file or in the helper file?

I can already confirm locally that the spec test works, but the issue only  appears on circleci...

Comment: Try `puts page.html` before the fill_in . You may need to add a sleep before it to allow the page to load/stabilize

Comment: Confirm that the page is loaded, but the test still fails. The form is available. Ugh.

Comment: Did you try changing from symbols to strings? Also, please add what was shown in your log to the question

Comment: Yes - I changed the symbols to strings. The log output is very long cause it shows all the css and gets called for every test being that the login_as is being used in every test. There are only three that fail using this method when the rest pass fine - can see its not a loading issue because the html is present - I added a bunch of puts to track and can clearly see the login page loads as soon as I use the find().click.

Comment: If the code works fine in other tests but fails in 3 then it very very likely is a loading issue.  If you can't post the part of the log from one of the failing tests then there's really not much else anybody will be able to do for you.